# CakePHP- querying a HABTM table and then accessing data

Tags: mysql, cakephp

CAKEPHP question

I am querying my HABTM table successfully and returning the `id` of every `student` with the given `group_id`.  This is my code for this.

`$students = $this->GroupsStudents->find('list', array('conditions' => array('group_id' => $id)));`

It works, no problem.  I need to somehow use this info (namely the student's `id`), which is stored in `$students`, to query my `students` table and extract student's names based on their id.

If someone could give me some insight on this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding you right. as you can see from this if you have the id you can easily get the students name even though i'm not sure why you would do this and not just foreach the name. 
    foreach ($students as $id => $name) {
       echo $students[$id]; // produces name
    }

Answer (score 0):

In Student model define relation with GroupStudent model as shown below:

```
var $hasMany = array(
'GroupStudent' => array(
    'className'     => 'GroupStudent',
    'foreignKey'    => 'student_id'
)
);
```

Then your write your query as

```
 $students = $this->Student->find('all',
                    array(
                   'conditions' => array('GroupStudent.group_id' => $id)
           'fields'=>array('Student.name','Student.id','GroupStudent.group_id'))
                   );
```

Note: Make sure your controller has `$uses=>array('Student','GroupStudent');` defined!
     and your are using plural names for model `GroupStudents` so correct them if possible

Comment: Just to clarify, ````groups_students```` is a relational database I have and isn't actually a model on its own.